# Populate multiple textboxs from openrecordset on Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to populate multiple textboxs from an openrecordset and getting the following error

Run-Time error 3601
Too few parameters. Expected 1

Here is my function

```
Function fnSearchAndPopulate() As Boolean
Dim d As DAO.Database, r As DAO.Recordset, strSQL As String
Set d = CurrentDb
If Me.txtEnterNumber = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Number", , "Error"
    Exit Function
End If
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM amipartnumbers Inner Join jdsubs on amipartnumbers.oemitem=jdsubs.oempartnumber WHERE " & txtEnterNumber.Value & " In (jdsubs.oempartnumber, jdsubs.oemsubnumber)"
Set r = d.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If r.EOF Then
   MsgBox "BAM # " & Me.txtEnterNumber & " does not exist!", , "No BAM #"
  Set d = Nothing
  Exit Function
End If
'get here if there is a record
r.MoveFirst
'populate whatever textboxes
Me.txtAMINumber = r!Item
Me.txtDescription = r!Description
Me.txtOEMsubnumber = r!OEMsubnumber

Set d = Nothing
Exit Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated** for non-numeric part numbers...

```
strSQL = " SELECT * FROM amipartnumbers Inner Join jdsubs on "     & _
         " amipartnumbers.oemitem=jdsubs.oempartnumber WHERE "     & _
         " jdsubs.oempartnumber= '" & txtEnterNumber.Value & "' or "  & _
         " jdsubs.oemsubnumber= '"  & txtEnterNumber.Value & "'"
```

Comment: Getting the same error. Run-Time error 3601 Too few parameters. Expected 1

Comment: Try to `Debug.Print` the SQL and run it directly in Access.  Are `amipartnumbers` and `jdsubs` both regular tables?

Comment: where do i place the Debug.Print?  Yes they are regular tables with 3 columns each

Comment: Okay i used the debug but not sure it showed me anything useful. SELECT * FROM jdsubs Inner Join amipartnumbers on  amipartnumbers.oemitem=jdsubs.oempartnumber WHERE  jdsubs.oempartnumber=AR77530 or  jdsubs.oemsubnumber=AR77530

Comment: sorry you might be confused by that debug. I had to swap the tables in the statement. strSQL = " SELECT * FROM jdsubs Inner Join amipartnumbers on " & _
         " amipartnumbers.oemitem=jdsubs.oempartnumber WHERE " & _
         " jdsubs.oempartnumber=" & txtEnterNumber.Value & " or " & _
         " jdsubs.oemsubnumber=" & txtEnterNumber.Value

Comment: Also i put this into my sql query and it works. Its just when using this function in my form is when i have issue. Are my populate commands right?

Comment: If your part numbers are not numeric (I assumed they were) then they need to be quoted in your SQL. See my updated answer.